# Getting an image from the database using WCF

Tags: javascript, ajax, database, wcf, mobile

I have a mobile application which needs to fetch images from the database and display it...I have a WCF service on the server that communicates with DB.

Is it possible to **retrieve an image from a database using WCF** ?

If yes,

How can i get it using an ajax call from my HTML/Javascript page ??

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading this article:  http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/fetching-image-using-wcf-rest-service/

From that article, instead of loading an image from disk ...

```
 FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(@"D:\a.jpg");
```

... you want to load the image from the database. The REST style should fit well with your AJAX needs.